# New branches of mathematics

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was wondering about the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58253/new-branches-of-math . IMO this question is extremely soft, and if someone has a good answer I doubt they will post it. I also do not understand why the comment, posted as an answer, got so many downvotes. It jokingly shows why the question is not good.

I tried to comment on this answer, but stackexchange did not allow me too. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering about the following question: [New branches of math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58253/new-branches-of-math). IMO this question is extremely soft, and if someone has a good answer I doubt they will post it.

The question is closed already.

Comment: That happened after I posted I think...

Comment: @Thomas Actually, it happened about 5 minutes earlier (but never mind).

Comment: I am a slow poster maybe.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to comment on this answer, but stackexchange did not allow me to. Why is this?

The answer has been deleted.

Comment: But when I tried to post, it wasn't I think (It just had some downvotes)

Comment: It is called a "[race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)". The answer was deleted between when you opened the page and saw it, and when you tried to add a comment.